# Transition functions of the tangent bundle of a projective variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

If we work (for example) in the category of differentiable manifolds, then i saw that it is standard calculating the transition functions of the tangent bundle of a differentiable manifold. It seems to me that this happens because we can "change chart". I couldn't find such a calculation, for example, for projective varieties.

Let $k=\overline{k}$. Let $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety, defined (for simplicity) by an irreducible, homogeneus polynomial $F$ (such that $(F)$ is radical). How can i do to calculate in this case the transition functions of the tangent bundle of $V$?
I am sorry if the question is trivial.

Comment: If $F=0$ is not smooth, the tangent sheaf is not a bundle.

Comment: @Mohan Sorry, i forgot the smoothness condition. So, what about If the variety is smooth?

Comment: The calculation is exactly the same as in the case of differentiable manifolds. Have you tried to write down this for the projective space itself first?

Comment: I can calculate only the equation of the space.

Comment: What are "the affine charts" for $\mathbb{P}^n$. Well, they correspond to dehomogenization in each of the variables $x_0,\dots, x_n$. Call the charts $H_0,\dots, H_n$ respectively. The transition functions are the morphisms from $H_i \to H_j$ given by $x_j/x_i$.

Comment: Now it works, thank you!